# kql window query sum over partition

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have the following table :

| Group | UserId | count_ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 | 7 |

I want to run a sum() over partition by group in order to calculate the total requests for every group and add a percentage column for every user in the group.

The expected output :

| Group | UserId | percent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 0.4 |
| 1 | 1 | 0.6 |
| 2 | 3 | 0.3 |
| 2 | 4 | 0.7 |

In SQL i would do something like the following :

```
select group,user,count_/sum(count_) over(partition by group) from table
```

How can i get this output ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least at this point, a JOIN is needed (similarly to a SQL solution without the use of windows functions)

```
let t = datatable(Group:int, UserId:int, count:int)
[
    1 ,2 ,2
   ,1 ,1 ,3
   ,2 ,3 ,3
   ,2 ,4 ,7
];
t
| summarize sum(['count']) by Group
| join kind=inner t on Group 
| project Group, UserId, percent = 1.0*['count']/sum_count
```

| Group | UserId | percent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 0.4 |
| 1 | 1 | 0.6 |
| 2 | 3 | 0.3 |
| 2 | 4 | 0.7 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA01PyQrCQAy9D8w/5NZWBrUqCErP4gd4KkW65DC1zZRpelD8eGdBMcnhLSHLgAwMBXQ1u2wGTC/WLNNJEyu4zWivXcStWYg9zKQopQAXOaidq0BUHmofiZP3/+QA6ihFdZaCpXjDvIxjbfULPUrLJMxOqgyaJ4T1vqk3muChqSs0EVp3paHogrcna3psOSrfUxVMaFsk/1G+3q5+ozdu0T3gDxU4CBvxAAAA)